# Table Structure for Complex json Data

Tags: c#, sql, json

**Solved** : I have solved this Problem By studying More posts..I just needed to create 2 tables ..one table have column Name (AAAA) and GroupId (1) which is foreign key of another table ..ANother Table have One more column ..which Contains the data 00,01,02 which maps to each groupId ...Thanks You for the valuable Posts

Sir, I am A bit Novice in creating DataBase Architecture ...I have jsonData coming from a Url as

```
[ { "AAAA":[{"0":"00"},{"1":"01"},{"2":"02"}]},
  { "BBBB":[{"0":"10"},{"1":"11"},{"2":"12"},{"3":"13"}]}]
```

this is the code I Tried to Get JSOn Data ...data is coming in nested  pairs.The problem I am Facing is that inner nested is not coming uniform ...in One Row there is array of 3 elements ,,in 2nd row there is an array of 2 elements..I needed to Create A Table Structure for this Data ...

```
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);

                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                dynamic jsonObject = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);
```

IN AddWatch jsonData is coming like that getting data with this Code:

```
jsonData :                          
    [0]-Count = 1                   
        --[0]                   
         --Key AAAA         
         --Value {object[2]}            
                      [0]-Count = 1     
                           [0]-{[0, 1111]}
                      [1]Count = 1      
                           [0]-{[0, 2222]}
```

Need some advice of how to Create a Table structure in this Case ...

Comment: Sir ,what's wrong I have Done ...Please Advice me

Comment: I have posted your solution below as Community Wiki. This means that other users who see your question in their own searches will see that an answer exists also. It would be desirable for you to accept this answer from the site's perspective - it will also result in you receiving additional rep which will increase your privileges on the site. I will not get any rep as I detached myself from it when it became Community Wiki.

Comment: Click the checkmark button next to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this Problem By studying More posts.

I just needed to create 2 tables:

- one table have column Name (AAAA) and GroupId (1) which is foreign key of another table
- ANother Table have One more column ..which Contains the data 00,01,02 which maps to each groupId